# Copied LyX file to another pc, cannot open it anymore

Tags: errors, lyx, auxiliary-files

I created a LyX file on laptop A, copied it on a pen drive and then on a different laptop B (all Windows).

Now on laptop B I am not allowed to open it, and I get the error message box:

```
LyX: Document format failure

C:/Users/Giuseppe/AppData/Local/Temp/1/lyx_tmpdir.ZPglpwaQ8028/Buffer_convertLyXFormatXXXXXX.lyx.IYUVfKay8028

 is not a readable LyX document.
```

I guess the issue is related to the fact that LyX uses some temporary directory to work. However I need to move the file to a different laptop.

How can I recover my work?

I need to continue working on laptop B, but I can go back on laptop A to recover the original file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you use the same LyX versions on both PCs? Which files did you transfer?

Comment: Hi, on pc B I have LyX Version 2.1.3 (6/02/2015), while on A I should have a more recent version (I installed it yesterday). I transferred only the main *.lyx file and a temporary file *.lyx~

Comment: @Giuseppe maybe the more recent version did make changes to the file format and the older version can't open those. Is there perhaps a possibility saving for older versions on laptop A? (I never used LyX, so I don't know)

Comment: Skillmon's idea is good. LyX does make file format changes among major versions (e.g. from 2.1.x to 2.2.x). I thought LyX gave a more useful error in this case (e.g. "file is from a newer version of LyX"), but perhaps not. Giuseppe do you get the same error if you create a very simple document (e.g. "hello world") on laptop A and move it to laptop B?

Comment: I will try and post the result

Comment: Tried with a simple one line file, same issue. Apparently, in addition, there is no option to save the file in a previous LyX version (although we are not sure that this is actually the source of the problem...)

Comment: Yes, you can export to a previous version. Go to File > Export and choose e.g. LyX 2.1.x.